# iPhone SDK 3.0 not detected by XCode 3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I have the latest XCode (3.2) running on Snow Leopard, and also have the iPhone 3.0 SDK installed. After XCode was installed, I can't create a new iPhone project with it. There are no iPhone options in the New window, nor is the OS listed anywhere in the Overview dropdown. My only option at this point seems to be downgrading to XCode 3.1, though I've seen 3.2 work perfectly with iPhone 3.0 at WWDC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must install the Snow Leopard version of the iPhone SDK (`iphone_sdk_3.0_gm_seed__snow_leopard.dmg`), not the Leopard copy (`iphone_sdk_3.0_gm_seed__leopard__9m2736.dmg`). My suggestion would be to run the following, and then install the Snow Leopard copy of the SDK again:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: If I had access to the SL seed, I would try this. Thanks.

Comment: The SL seed is available for free when you join ADC.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1_beta_3/iphone_sdk_3.1_beta_3__snow_leopard.dmg

iPhone SDK for iPhone OS 3.1 beta 3 provides support for developing applications for iPhone OS 3.1. This developer preview of iPhone SDK for Snow Leopard installer includes only the SDK components for iPhone OS development, and requires that Xcode 3.2 already be installed on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.